# Oracle Github Integration Automation

Tags: git, oracle, automation, integration

I wanted to check if there are any tools (preferably freeware) or scripts that can be used to automate/integrate the git with Oracle. I'm looking for following features:

1. Validate the code in Git against code in Oracle Schema. Git should match Oracle (production).
2. Send out mail alerts in case of discrepancies.

Regards.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can write you own [Git hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/uz/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) in any scripting language (python, perl, bash, you name it) you fancy, to do what ever you like. So yes: there are such tools. There is even a [dedicated website](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-git-hooks-to-automate-development-and-deployment-tasks) on how to use and develop custom git hooks.

Comment: Was this helpful to you?